# Powershell instantiated COM object randomly fails credentials

Tags: excel, windows, powershell, dcom

Windows Server 2019 Standard version 1809 Build 17763.168. Intel Xeon CPU @2.60GHz (4 processors) 24GB RAM

Task Manager to run PowerShell script to instantiate Excel DOM object to translate old DBase IV files to Excel .csv files.
[File CDownloads](https://www.filemail.com/d/xvkdsfcfskfgsyj)

Powershell command: $E = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application DCOM Identity properties: attached.
Successful Powershell Transcript: attached.

Failed Powershell Transcript: attached.

Server Manager > Local Server > Events > Error: attached.

When the configured Identity in Component Services > Excel fails credentials in PowerShell, to rectify this, I simply set the Identity to 'The launching user.', Apply, then set the Identity back to 'The interactive user.', Apply, and it works again for a few days before failing identity credentials within 1-5 days. Please advise on how to get the COM object instantiation in PowerShell to retain credentials and discontinue failing. I have tried defining the identity user to a service account and admin with the same failure results.

Does anyone have any idea how to get this process to stop failing credentials in Powershell?

New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a The server
process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and
password. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000401A).